# How to copy all maven dependencies when packaging using assembly file?

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project A that has some dependencies in its POM.
A has a parent project B and a grand-parent project C.

When packaging A, using an assembly file, I'd like to put all necessary dependencies for A inside a directory in the packaged project.

Currently the I can only package the dependencies that are in A's POM.
I didn't find a way to package B's and C's dependencies that are necessary to A.
Do you know how I could do that?

Here's the assembly XML:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin    /assembly/1.1.2"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">  
    <id>bundle</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <!--Include runtime dependencies-->
            <outputDirectory>${ser.depdir}</outputDirectory>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get the generated application jar-->
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get application resources-->
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.sh</include>
                <include>log4j2.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get misc user files-->
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>README*</include>
                <include>LICENSE*</include>
                <include>NOTICE*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>  
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

And A's POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>ser</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ser-art</artifactId>
    <name>SER ART</name>
    <description>desc</description>
    <properties>
        <ser.depdir>${project.artifactId}-dependencies</ser.depdir>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>../config/test</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mainClass</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>${ser.depdir}/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>./conf/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                        <exclude>*.sh</exclude>
                        <exclude>log4j2.xml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${ser.depdir}</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>ser-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>utilities-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Create a separate module with packaging pom, add all dependencies you need and create assembly descriptor with dependency set and that should work without the need to copy file to a directory etc.

Comment: the maven-dependency-plugin does exactly what I expect it to do. It's the assembly.xml that seems to be missing something ...

Answer (score 1):

1. A workaround from top of my head could be that you use "maven dependency plugin" copy phase to copy everything to a certain dir and then using "fileset" descriptor of assembly pluging. But this will make your pom look dirty.
2. I have not tried but assembly plugin supports the packaging of transitive dependency. That is the correct solution in your case.